# Developer access to Application Support Directory on iOS 17

Tags: ios, xcode, file, xcode15, ios17

How can I access the contents of the application support directory of my own apps on IOS 17 devices?

Until iOS 16 the answer in Xcode was to open the Devices and Simulators window in Xcode, select the attached device and the Xcode-installed app on it, and download the container. Then I would select the container in Finder, select Show Package Contents with the secondary mouse button, and find the folder under AppData > Library > Application Support, with all its content.

This still works with Xcode 15.0.1 on an iOS 16 device, but not anymore on an iOS 17.1 device. The Library folder from the same app there contains only Caches, Saved Application State, WebKit subfolders, but no Application Support folder anymore.

I know from the console and debugger output that my app has successfully written files to Library/Application%20Support/ on the device, through an URL formed by `SearchPathDirectory.applicationSupportDirectory`, and no exceptions were raised.

Has the Application Support directory moved on iOS 17, or is the container download broken? How can I access the files that my app wrote to it from outside the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory "~/Library/Application Support" does not exist, by default. I have to create the directory to write files in it.

I also see that the directory is missing when you follow your procedure to download the container in Xcode.

I found a work around using iMazing, it shows the Application Support and contents after it has been created. I am not recommending iMazing, and there are other similar tools. This is just my work-around for the Xcode issue.

Comment: Thanks, iMazing does the job. I did use it on a previous Mac, but forgot the name. Yes, the application support folder has to be created programmatically, but that was not the issue.