# Download Core Data SQLite Data File From iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am trying to browse data that has been saved to Core Data from my application that I am running. The iPhone is running iOS 17 and I have Xcode 15.

Prior to this update, I used to be able to navigate to the following path to download the file:

Window -> Devices and Simulators -> 'Click on my app' -> Download Container.

Within this folder I could press 'Show Package Contents' and then navigate to the Core Data folder and see the data. This was great because then I could use a SQLite browser to view the data. It seems like this is no longer a thing.

Has anyone else figured out what to try?

Comment: I now have to download rather than show.  Select the device and then app in Devices & Simulators, then click on the 3 dots button underneath and choose download container.  Just checked on my iOS17 device and it downloads OK and can open the .sqlite file. [The show container doesn't seem to work]

Comment: @flanker
What is the path to the file once you open the contents? I dont see it anymore when I do download like I used to

Comment: I have always been downloading the container, and when I do, I press 'Show Package Contents' after a right click, then go to 'AppData' -> 'Library': Then I see three folders:
'Caches', 'Saved Application State', WebKit

None of these have my Coredata objects in it that I know are being saved. 

(While debugging I can print out objects that are fetched and I can see there are valid values in there that I saved)

Comment: I'm finding them in AppData/Library/Application Support ... which you don't seem to have.  On previous OS versions they've been in caches (this was 16.x I think)

Comment: Yeah that is where I used to find it on iOS 16, but I dont have the 'Application Support' folder anymore

Comment: Related: [Developer access to Application Support Directory on iOS 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77439194/developer-access-to-application-support-directory-on-ios-17).

Comment: Interesting ^^^ I've not had to create the folder.  Can you just access `container.viewContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.persistentStores.first?.url` to see where sqlite is creating its store files?

Comment: When I do, I see file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<UUID>/Library/Application%20Support/<App Name>.sqlite

So it exists but to access this path, I thought I need to be able to download the container which I cannot @flanker